# Anagram of a string using pointer arithmatic

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Here is the code to find the anagram for a string. I am using pointer array to do it but want to do it using pointer arithmetic.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int check_anagram(char [], char []); 

int main()
{
    char a[100], b[100];
    int flag;

    printf("Enter first string\n");
    gets(a);

    printf("Enter second string\n");
    gets(b);

    flag = check_anagram(a, b);

    if (flag == 1)
        printf("\"%s\" and \"%s\" are anagrams.\n", a, b);
    else
        printf("\"%s\" and \"%s\" are not anagrams.\n", a, b);

    return 0;
}

int check_anagram(char a[], char b[])
{
    int first[26] = {0}, second[26] = {0}, c = 0;

    while (a[c] != '\0')
    {
       first[a[c]-'a']++;
       c++;
    }

    c = 0;

    while (b[c] != '\0')
    {
       second[b[c]-'a']++;
       c++;
    }

    for (c = 0; c < 26; c++)
    {
       if (first[c] != second[c])
          return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

--> How to using pointer arithmetic and find it.

In the while loop :

```
while (a[c] != '\0')
{
   first[a[c]-'a']++;
   c++;
}
```

--> Can we modify it to below way so that it will work

```
while(*(a+c)!='\0')
{
   *(first *(a+c)-'a')++;  
    c++;
}
```

Comment: Anagram examples : gun -->nug  ; game-->agem

Comment: When you use arrays in C and C++ you're using pointers already - converting it to use raw pointers will not offer any speed advantage and it will make the code much harder to read. Is there a reason you're doing this?

Comment: BTW, you don't need two histograms to detect anagrams, you can detect anagrams with a single histogram and only two loops, so you can speed up your program by 33%.

Comment: I was given a requirement to do it via pointer arithematic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`first[a[c]-'a']++` = `first[*(a+c)-'a']++` = `(*(first+(*(a+c)-'a')))++`

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to process an array using pointers is by initializing a pointer to the beginning of the array, and then increment it, rather than doing pointer arithmetic to index from the beginning each time.

```
char *c = a;
while (*c != 0) {
    first[*c - 'a']++;
    c++;
}
```

If you need to use pointer arithmetic for `first` as well, then it would be:

```
    (*(first + *c - 'a'))++
```